# android, cursor returning boolean value?

Tags: android, sqlite

Can an Android Cursor return a boolean value? I've looked at the docs and there was no info on it?

If not - then is there an alternative way to get a boolean value from a SQLite table?

Comment: use int ... like in C ... 0 means false other means true

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The android implementation of SQLite3 doesn't properly support boolean values. You will need to use integers set to 0 or 1 and write some code to convert that to a boolean e.g.

```
int x = cursor.getInt(...);
return x == 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use enum type with values 'Y' and 'N' to represent the boolean value

Answer (score 1):

Another way is just to pass as String rather than boolean and then parse it back to boolean:

```
int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(<key>);
String str = cursor.getString(index);
boolean bool = Boolean.parseBoolean(str);
```